# Why web.<environment>.config is present after File Transform in release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In my release pipeline I am using **File Transform** option for my web.config.
I have web.config and web.staging.config
File transform is working and changes are applied in web.config but why web.staging.config is still present in the final deployed package.

Am I missing any configuration or this a normal behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this issue , with XML file transformation, the web.xxx.config file is required. The transform will be applied when publish web app to web deploy package or publish to server directly per to the configuration.

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops&tabs=Classic#xml-transformation): You need to create a Web Application package with the necessary configuration and transform files.

So if you want to removing all config transforms, as a workaround , you could add a [Delete-files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/delete-files?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts) task in the end to remove all configuration files. For example:

```
Source Folder:
    $(wwwRoot)\

Contents:
    **\*.staging.config
```

Here is a [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50946562/how-avoid-environment-config-transformations-being-deployed-on-server) with similar issue , you can refer to it for details.

Comment: Thanks Hugh!
But when I publish through the Visual Studio publish option using the staging configuration, web.staging.config file does not appear in the published folder.
How is it deleted from the published folder automatically?